# different outputs from systemd-analyze time

Tags: virtualbox, systemd

I have on the same physical machine an Ubuntu 18.04 native system and the same version in a VirtualBox.

In the native system I get:

```
jean@myLinux:~$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 7.232s (firmware) + 11.828s (loader) + 3.583s (kernel) + 1min 57.131s (userspace) = 2min 19.775s
graphical.target reached after 28.397s in userspace
```

In the virtual system I get:

```
Startup finished in 13.650s (kernel) + 28.546s (userspace) = 42.196s
graphical.target reached after 28.391s in userspace
```

I am not asking about the values, but why do I get a different output format? The systemd version is the same on both systems (237).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *format* seems the same to me ("Startup finished in a + b + c ... = x"). There's just some missing values, that of the firmware for example. AFAICT systemd obtains that value from EFI variables, and if your VirtualBox VM isn't configured to provide UEFI booting for the virtualized OS, there won't be any EFI  information for systemd, so it omits that information. Something similar probably applies to the bootloader time.

Comment: Yes, firmware and loader are only available in UEFI systems.